# Failed to run command eventually Parse Server

Tags: ios, json, swift, heroku, parse-server

I am running the `Parse Server` on `Heroku` and all was working well until I ran my app and got the error: `Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."`

I don't have the slightest clue whats causing this, the error appears immediately when the app is run. I connected my `iOS` app to the Parse Server and am writing in `Swift`.

The only code that runs when the app is launched checks if there is a user and if they have verified their account:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    if currentUser == nil || currentUser!["phoneNumberVerified"] == nil {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("showLogInSignUpView", sender: self)

    } else {

        if let numberIsVerified = currentUser!["phoneNumberVerified"] as? Bool {

            if currentUser != nil && numberIsVerified == false {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerifyUserView", sender: self)

            } else if currentUser != nil && numberIsVerified == true {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showDiscoverView", sender: self)

            } else {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showLogInSignUpView", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it's related to your previous execution of `saveEventually`, can you post that?

Comment: Thats the thing the only code I run is what I posted.

Comment: Ah, you haven't authenticated yet. I think that's your problem.

Comment: How do I authenticate?

Comment: Oh no, my mistake. I misread your code. Are you sure the crash is not inside one of the other VCs? You should include a break on all exceptions.

Comment: Ok so I added a Breakpoint for all exceptions but nothing happened and I still got the error

Comment: So if you comment out all the segues, does it still happen?

Comment: Yes it does.... Sorry i just had to add more characters to post

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look about your data type.Using break point before the crash.Make sure you have use the same type to receive the data with your server.Try to check the [your_data_object class].I have get the same trouble when I connect with my server.They returned a JSON but it actually is String.So I do this `NSDictionary *jsonDict =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:successReturn options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];`
  Hope may be helpful.

Comment: I read something similar to this. Where did you put that code?

Comment: the successReturn is the server response,you should some thing to receive it,but you need change it type first,you could put it in the success return block.Hope may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but i mean where is that located? In my swift project? App Delegate? or index.js ect?

Comment: Maybe I have gave the wrong answer,I can not understand it clear.